# Visible Copy paste function causing an error

Tags: vba, excel

I'm dealing with an error and I don't really know what to do with it.

[image: The error]

```
Private Sub commandbutton1_click()

Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = Sheets("inbd")
Dim wsDestination As Worksheet: Set wsDestination = Sheets("sheet1")

LastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    ws.Range("A1:N" & LastRow).AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=Worksheets("sheet1").Cells(1, 5).Value
```

This line of code below is giving me an error.

```
    Sheets("INBD").Range("D2", Cells(Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Cells(2, 4).Copy _
    Destination:=Sheets(1).Range("J1:K2")
```

It's supposed to copy the first visible cell in column D. (Credit: This part of the code was given to me by user "Marcucciboy2") I can't figure out how to integrate it with the rest of the code though.

```
    Application.Run ("Macro8")
    Application.Run ("Macro4")
    Application.Run ("Macro5")
    Application.Run ("Macro6")

LastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    ws.Range("A1:N" & LastRow).AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=Worksheets("sheet1").Cells(1, 5).Value

ws.Range("A1:N" & LastRow).AutoFilter Field:=1

End Sub
```

Comment: `Cells(Rows.Count, "D")` references the ActiveSheet. If that's not `Sheets("INBD")` then that would cause an error.  Use `Sheets("INBD").Cells(Sheets("INBD").Rows.Count, "D")`

Comment: thank you, much appreciated

Comment: tried it didn't work

Answer (score 0):

```
 Sheets("INBD").Range("D2", Cells(Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
```

returns a block of cells one column wide - so it can't have a cells(2,4) as that defines something in the fourth column. You want cells(1,1) - the first cell within the visible cells.

Cells defines a cell with reference to a specified range unless you use Worksheets(X).cells in which case it's by reference to the whole spreadsheet: so Sheets("INBD").Cells(2,4) is cell D2, but Range("A100:D200").cells(2,4) is cell D200

Comment: In the immediate window in the VB editor enter  ? Sheets("INBD").Range("D2", Cells(Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).address  and see what cells it thinks are visible